# Capture GMOCK string parameter

Tags: googlemock

If I have the following interface member function:

```
virtual bool print_string(const char* data) = 0;
```

with the following mock

```
MOCK_METHOD1(print_string, bool(const char * data));
```

Is it possible to capture the string that is passed to print_string()?

I tried to:

```
char out_string[20];     //
SaveArg<0>(out_string);  // this saves the first char of the sting
```

this saves the first char of the sting but not the whole string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Class**

```
struct Foo {
    virtual bool print_string(const char* data) = 0;
};
```

**Mock**

```
struct FooMock {
    MOCK_METHOD1(print_string, bool(const char * data));
};
```

**Test**

```
struct StrArg {
    bool print_string(const char* data) { 
        arg = data; 
        return true; 
    }
    string arg;
};

TEST(FooTest, first) {
    FooMock f;
    StrArg out_string;

    EXPECT_CALL(f, print_string(_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(&out_string, &StrArg::print_string));
    f.print_string("foo");
    EXPECT_EQ(string("foo"), out_string.arg);
}
```

You can always use Invoke to capture parameter value in structure.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like:

```
char* p = out_string[0];
SaveArg<0>(&p);
```

since SaveArg(pointer) save the Nth argument to *pointer.

I think if you just need to validate the content of the array without deep copy, there is no need to create another array since only the pointer to the array could be obtained using this method.