# gmock save argument string

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I hope there is an easier way to do this... I need to capture the string which is passed as an argument to a mock.

The mock

```
class web_api_mock : public iweb_api
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(
            (bool), 
            http_post, 
            (const etl_normal_string &, const char*), 
            (override));

};
```

I want to capture the `char *` passed to the mock as second argument. I need to construct some json structure from it, and I want to check if a certain element has a certain value.

I had to spend a lot of time to get it to work, eventually copying the trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390218/capture-gmock-string-parameter). This brilliant mind figured out you can rely on the gmock's `Invoke`.

The `EXPECT_CALL`

```
http_post_args args;

EXPECT_CALL(_web_api_mock, http_post(etl_string_equals(url), _))
    .WillOnce(
        DoAll(
            Invoke(&args, &http_post_args::capture),
            Return(true)));
```

Here I am invoking all arguments of the mock to a struct which I defined as follows

```
struct http_post_args
{
    void capture(etl_normal_string url, const char * p)
    {
        payload = std::string(p);
    }

    std::string payload;
};
```

And finally, I get my hands on the `char *` and do whatever I want afterwards.

It seems awfully complicated to save an argument when it's of the type `char *`.

My first attempt was the obvious mistake I guess many before (and after) me made: using the `SaveArgPointee` which will copy only the first element of the string and gives me with a string where the first character is correct, but the remaining string is filled with random mem.

My second attempt was to define an `ACTION_P`. This "almost" worked. In the callstack I could see the string I am interested in until the very last stackframe, where the `args` simply seem not to be passed to the actual implementation of my custom `ACTION_P`.

```
ACTION_P2(capture_string, url, payload) 
{ 
    /* if I break in the debugger, and go 1 stackframe up, 
    I can see that gmock holds my string in varargs as second element
    But I couldn't find a way to access it here*/
}
```

I also tried the `ACTION_TEMPLATE` but I am not c++ enough to understand what they are trying to explain me on gmock cookbook.

So my final question: is the above working trick with `http_post_args` struct really "the only way" to capture a `const char *` being passed as an argument to a mock?

If it SHOULD be possible using `ACTION_P` or `ACTION_TEMPLATE` would somebody be so kind to provide an actual working example with a `const char *`?

Comment: Do you want to copy the passed string into new memory or just get the pointer to be used?

Comment: BTW, *I need to construct some json structure from it, and I want to check if a certain element has a certain value.* - that sounds like you want a custom matcher, rather than capturing the string and using it later. Although it may or may not be be easier to write than what you want, can't tell for a general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a lambda, like so ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/7qTEdfczn)):

```
TEST(SomeTest, Foo)
{
    std::string payload;
    web_api_mock m;
    EXPECT_CALL(m, http_post(Eq("url"), _))
        .WillOnce([&](const std::string &, const char* p){ 
            payload = p; 
            return true;
        });
    
    m.http_post("url", "foo string");
    EXPECT_THAT(payload, Eq("foo string"));
}
```

No additional `http_post_args` or actions etc required.
Of course, you could also change the `payload` to a `const char*` if you want to "capture" the raw char pointer. But be careful with the lifetime of the pointed to characters, in this case.

You hinted that your real code will need to parse the payload string as json and check for a certain element. It might lead to more readable tests when you create a [dedicated matcher](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#NewMatchers) that does this. To show a rough draft ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/W5efs7e1E)):

```
MATCHER_P(ContainsJsonElement, expectedElement, "")
{
    const char * payload = arg;
    // Parse payload as json, check for element, etc.
    const bool foundElement = std::string(payload) == expectedElement;
    return foundElement;
}

TEST(SomeTest, Foo) 
{
    web_api_mock m;
    EXPECT_CALL(m, http_post(Eq("url"), ContainsJsonElement("foo string")));
    m.http_post("url", "foo string");
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, these are useful tips! Going to try them both out. Thx for the excellent explanation!

Comment: OK, it both works fine. I am used to write tests with the AAA (arrange, act, assert) approach. Using the matcher it is actually asserting inside the matcher. And the matcher is inside the EXPECT_CALL. It feels a bit awkward. Might be very personal though. What's your take on that?

Comment: If you have `EXPECT_CALL(..., ContainsJsonElement)`, I wouldn't say that the assertion is inside the matcher. The matcher is just an elaborate predicate: There is **no** code (in the sense of `EXPECT_...` or `ASSERT_...`) in the matcher itself that causes a test to fail. Thus, I'd say the assertion is the `EXPECT_CALL`, not the `ContainsJsonElement`. Just for technical reasons, you can't have the `EXPECT_CALL` after the actual call. In the end, what matters is that the test (and optimally its output) is readable, regardless of idioms. I think the 3 lines with the matcher are pretty readable.

Comment: Alright. I'll stick with `MATCHER` approach. It indeed reads super easy

Comment: Also note that the error message in case of a test failure can be improved by extending the matcher as [documented](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#NewMatchers) using the (in this case third) argument `""` or the `result_listener`.